# чем дебажить JSF?

Tags: java, отладка, jsf, web-apps, primefaces

Ребят, помогите кто?!
Я вот тут давно что-то JSFом не занимался, появилась необходимость, и вот теперь у меня реально ступор, а как/чем дебажить JSF/PrimeFaces приложения-то?

Comment: А в чем проблемма то?  Северная часть дебажится как обычно никаких специальных знаний не требуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Что происходит в компонентах серверной части - стандартно `Remote JVM Debug` в вашей среде разработки.
2. Что происходит в браузере отладке поддаётся очень плохо. Для `AJAX`-запросов внимательно смотрите ответы в отладчике браузера, нередко по ним можно понять что произошло. Например в ответе есть `Validation Failed`, а вы забыли обновлять компонент отображения сообщений валидации. В результате - молча ничего не происходит.
3. Если что-то на странице не работает - выкидываем с неё всё лишнее до тех пор, пока не заработает, вплоть до отключения шаблонов. Потом постепенно возвращаем и смотрим после добавления какого компонента опять сломалось. Способ не красивый, но мне помогал неоднократно.
4. Можно для PrimeFaces добавлять компонент `p:log`, но мне как-то не помогает...

Comment: Ещё можно добавить на страницу xhtml тег <ui:debug /> и в браузере на этой странице же ввести комбинацию клавиш CTRL + SHIFT + D, должно отобразится визуальное представление иерархии всех компонент JSF, и другая полезная информация.